# Setting an accessible Python function's variable from outside a function

Tags: python, binding, scope

I am curious how I can assign a variable from outside a function object. Before I tried it, I *thought* I knew how it can be done.

```
>>> def f():
...     print(x)
... 
>>> f.x=2
>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>>
```

I then tried:

```
>>> class c:
...     def f(self):
...         print(x)
... 
>>> y=c();y.x=2;y.f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

The same error. Now, I thought, this just *has* to work:

```
>>> class c:
...     def makef(self):
...         return lambda x=x: print(x)
... 
>>> y = c();y.x = 2;y.makef()()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in makef
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
```

Alas, it did not. How can I assign a variable accessible to a function after the function has been defined? This is just a curiosity. There's really no reason (that I can think of) for not just passing a parameter.

Comment: Why the negative votes?  The guy asked a very plain question "how I assign a variable from outside a function object". Regardless of whether it's a good idea, or bad, it's a legitimate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a way of doing what I was trying to accomplish. I need to modify the object's dictionary:

```
>>> def f():
...     print(x)
... 
>>> f.__dict__['x'] = 2
>>> f()
2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
    def f(self):
        print self.x

a = Name()
a.x = 'Value'
a.f()
```

output

```
$ Value
```

Comment: That's not really what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you define your variable in the main program, you can then use the global keyword to reference it.

```
bah = 1

def function():
  global bah

   bah = 2
```